# How to get around spock Data provider is null error

Tags: groovy, junit, spock, data-driven-tests

I have a SpringBootTest that reads in properties from application.properties. The setup code uses the `@Value` annotation to set the values accordingly. One of these properties is an array of names.

I am trying to write a data driven test using Spock. The where statement is using these names that are initialized in the setup:

```
expect:
retrievedName == value
where:
value << getNames()
```

This always fails with `org.spockframework.runtime.SpockExecutionException: Data provider is null`.
It appears that the getNames() call is invoked before the properties are initialized in the setup code.  If I do not use the where statement (data driven testing), all works fine. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question instead of just incoherent snippets. Then the chance that anyone can reproduce and solve your problem is way higher than with this kind of foggy question. So please edit your question accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use data initialized in the `setup` section as a source for data driven tests. As per [the docs](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/spock_primer.html#_where_blocks):

> Although it is declared last, the `where` block is evaluated before the feature method containing it runs.

You can try and use `setupSpec()` methods and `@Shared` fields as a workaround.

See [here](http://meetspock.appspot.com/script/5078447311290368) for an example.